# How to display responsive 5 poker card images with correct aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display 5 poker cards laid side by side with horizontal margin just like on a poker table. I tried this but I can't make it display:

I also want this to be responsive that is it preserves aspect ratio when resized.

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.is2d .two.hearts {background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')}
```

```html
<div class="poker is2d">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="card two hearts"></div> 
      <div class="card two hearts"></div>
      <div class="card two hearts"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't have any content, so nothing will display. Use a container that has a width associated with it so that the cards will take the width and the height specified.

Answer (score 0):

As Armedin said, you do not have any content inside your div. `Width` and `height 100%` won't do anything.

I suggest you to put the image not as background, as it won't change the dimensions of the div. Use `img` tag and `display: inline;` for the card div.

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="poker is2d">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="card two hearts"> <img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'/></div> 
      <div class="card two hearts"> <img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'/></div>
      <div class="card two hearts"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** If you do not want to use `img` you can put the img to invisible and then use the background image as the div would still have the dimensions of the img tag inside. Not a good solution, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Learn flex or grid; both very useful for things like this.

Flex example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div> 
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about body was the poker table and container had to be a small portion of the body in the middle.

Comment: Use a flex within a flex or use a grid for a more custom layout - they will take a little time to learn and understand but it is worth it.

Comment: Wouldn't I have more control with position absolute. Also should I set the width height on the container or the card.

Comment: Theres lots of ways... I'm just recommending you opt for a modern approach since it appears you're learning stuff. Up to you!